# Go integer data race

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

Question about Go data race on int type.
When I run below program by `go run -race main.go`,

```
package main

import "fmt"

var i int

func main() {

    go func() {
        i = 10
    }()

    i = 5

    fmt.Println(i)
}
```

It shows data race warning.

```
~  $ go run -race main.go
5
==================
WARNING: DATA RACE
Write at 0x000000605908 by goroutine 7:
  main.main.func1()
      /home/dty1er/main.go:80 +0x3a

Previous write at 0x000000605908 by main goroutine:
  main.main()
      /home/dty1er/main.go:83 +0x56

Goroutine 7 (running) created at:
  main.main()
      /home/dty1er/main.go:79 +0x46
==================
Found 1 data race(s)
exit status 66
```

I know why this data race occurs; `var i` is accessed by 2 goroutines concurrently without any synchronization.
What I don't understand is the actual problem of this code. In my understanding, because `i` is `int`, (and my pc is 64 bit), the `i` is actually 64 bit. And on 64 bit machine, the `i` can be read/written atomically. So I don't think there is actual problem.

For example, if the type is map or slice, because the memory access by the CPU cannot be atomic, so its intermediate state can be visible sometimes and it is problem.

But when I am just using int type value, even if there is a data race, it looks there are no actual problem.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: See the old [What could possibly go wrong?](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/blogs/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong.html) blog-post.

Comment: *And on 64 bit machine, the i can be read/written atomically.* This is way too much of a simplification. You have multiple cores, branch predictions, compiler optimizations and probably most important of all, the fact that the language specifies that this is not allowed just to name a few reasons you can't do this with reliable results.

Comment: You are also not writing code at the machine level, you are writing code for the Go compiler and runtime. If the language spec says it's not valid, then it doesn't matter what the hardware does. If no extra instructions are needed to assign the integer value on your hardware (note that Go runs on many different architectures), then the _compiler_ if free to do so.

Comment: _See the old What could possibly go wrong? blog-post_ I should have read this earlier. Thank you!

Comment: _the fact that the language specifies that this is not allowed_ I couldn't find in Go language specification this is not allowed. Is it a common behavior on various languages?

Comment: _ If the language spec says it's not valid_ It seems like Go language specification doesn't mention it, but I read some articles then it seems like undefined behavior will occur when a data race happens.

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/mem is part of the language specification.

Answer (score 5):

> Is my understanding correct?

No it isn't. A program with a data race is undefined and using an int doesn't magically make this data race go away. Compilers and hardware are no longer that simple as you might be used to from the 80s. Data races are a *major* bug.

You can use sync/atomic to work with integers in a race-free way but a simple int is plain wrong in this setting.

Comment: Thank you. Now I found if a data race happens, the program gets undefined behavior and it's the problem. I still don't fully understand what causes the undefined behavior clearly (it seems like it's caused by compiler optimization or some cpu optimization), and I'll next dig into it.

Answer (score -2):

When you run that code, what do you expect to get printed, 5 or 10? You can never be sure what it is, which is what the data race is. The fact that int in Go is atomic is not related in this case.

Comment: You have it the wrong way around. int is not atomic. This code could be rewritten with sync/atomic and it would then be race-free but still unpredictable. Just because something is unpredictable doesn't mean it's a data-race (consider select statements with multiple cases, for instance).

Comment: An `int` in Go is definitely not atomic. It _may_ be on some architectures at the hardware level, but Go runs on many different architectures, and the same language spec must apply to them all.